# trying to create a popover control with a datepicker in it that pops up when i click on a UITextField

Tags: ipad, uidatepicker, popover, uitextfielddelegate

So I've seen this question answered in such a way where someone says "use the TextFieldShouldBeginEditing which is a method in the UITextField delegate protocol"

I'm already using the popover delegate protocol in my original view:

```
@interface AddChildViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
```

and then I have the UITextField as an IBOutlet in that view. Do I instead have to create a new view and viewcontroller that just contains the UITextField?

Please be specific about what I'm supposed to put in which file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer but here it is.

1. You can implement more than one protocols in a class

   eg: `@interface AddChildViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UItextFieldDelegate>`
2. From `Interface Builder` (or `Storyboard`) drag the delegate property of `textfield` to the `AddChildViewController`
3. Do all the resizing and adding a date picker or a calendar component in this method:

`TextFieldShouldBeginEditing`

//you are done